# Create a new pandas column that is a list of lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have two tables that look something like this:

```
data = [['tom', [3,5]], ['nick', [3,8]], ['juli', [3]]] 
dfA = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'job_id'])


data1 = [['coder', 3], ['cook', 5], ['cop', 8]]
df_B = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['job', 'job_id'])
```

And I'd like to add a column to the first table such that it looks like this:

```
data_comb = [['tom', ['coder','cook']], ['nick', ['coder','cop']], ['juli', ['coder']]] 
df_comb = pd.DataFrame(data_comb, columns = ['Name', 'jobs_done'])
```

I am getting an unhashable list error likely due to the list within the column. Pointers on how to solve this will be appreciated.

Comment: Your same code working for me and got the same output as below answers.     
      Name jobs_done
0 tom [coder, cook]
1 nick [coder, cop]
2 juli [coder]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mapper = df_B.set_index('job_id').to_dict()['job']
dfA['job_id'] = dfA['job_id'].apply(lambda lst: [mapper.get(x) for x in lst])
```

output:

```
>>>dfA

    Name    job_id
0   tom     ['coder', 'cook']
1   nick    ['coder', 'cop']
2   juli    ['coder']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary to map the lists:

```
lookup = {key : value for value, key in data1}
dfA['job_id'] = dfA.job_id.apply(lambda x : [lookup[v] for v in x])
print(dfA)
```

**Output**

```
   Name         job_id
0   tom  [coder, cook]
1  nick   [coder, cop]
2  juli        [coder]
```